# Google-maps geocoding service

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Hi I'm using google documentation in geocoding service.

The script should display the location Casablanca but it still show the default location in austalia

**The problem is that geocoder.geocode(...) is not executed**

```
function initMap() {

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        scrollwheel: false,
        zoom: 8,
      });
codeAddress(geocoder,map);
}
function codeAddress(geocoder, map)
{
  var addr = "Casablanca";
  geocoder.geocode( {'addr':addr}, function(results, status) 
  {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
    {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.addr);//center the map over the result
      //place a marker at the location
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
      {
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.addr
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
   }
  });
}
```

PS:
I'm using GooglMapper https://github.com/bradcornford/Googlmapper

I appreciate any help.

Comment: What exactly is your problem now?

Comment: It should display the location Casablanca but it still show the default location in austalia

Comment: @JoachimRohde the problem is that geocoder.geocode is not executed.
You have any idea ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
geocoder.geocode( {'addr':addr}, function(results, status)
```

Should be:

```
geocoder.geocode( {'address':addr}, function(results, status)
```

The GeocoderRequest object literal contains the following fields:

```
{
 address: string,
 location: LatLng,
 placeId: string,
 bounds: LatLngBounds,
 componentRestrictions: GeocoderComponentRestrictions,
 region: string
}
```

Taken from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)

Comment: There was two more error. I show them in my answer.
+1 to the field of The GeocoderRequest object it helps me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Answer For my problem

```
map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.addr);
```

Should be

```
map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
```

And

```
position: results[0].geometry.addr
```

Should Be

```
position: results[0].geometry.location
```